# How to remove this plastic pipe elbow

Tags: plumbing, pipe, plumbing-fixture

I cannot seem to get this plastic pipe elbow (pictured below) off. It joins a plastic pipe to an outside tap and the elbow has a crack in.

[image]

I've tried twisting, pulling and pushing it - but it won't budge. Is there some special tool I need, or perhaps it needs squeezing with pliers whilst being twisted?

Comment: Any markings or part numbers on it? How much slack in the PEX (plastic) pipe? How far from the PEX to the fixture? You may just need to cut each pipe at the fitting and rerun it. If you have to do that it may be easier to run PEX from the junction shown here all the way up to the fixture instead of the copper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the UK (where question poster is located), there are several distinct types of plastic push-fit connectors. You can get specialized tools to help undo each type.

- John Guest Speedfit
- Wavin [Hep2O](http://uk.wavin.com/web/catalogue/heating-cooling/plumbing-systems/pushfit-hep2o.htm)
- Floplast Flo-Fit
- etc

Yours are [Hep2o](http://www.screwfix.com/p/hep2o-plastic-push-fit-90-elbow-15mm-pack-of-10/4395f)

[image]

and can be released with a [Hepkey](http://www.screwfix.com/search?search=heptool) - there is a [tool selection guide](http://www.plumbed-in.com/DemountingToolGuide.pdf).

---

Hep2O

[image]

---

Speedfit
[image]

---

FloPlast

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see the branding as it's so faint, but it does appear to be a "Hep2O". I will get the special tool to match the part

Answer (score 3):

Many push-fit fittings are not designed to be removable. If that were a sharkbite connector, you get get a special removal tool.

> **How do I disconnect SharkBite push-fit fittings?**
>
> The only way to disconnect the SharkBite push-fit fitting is with a
>   SharkBite Disconnection Clip or SharkBite Disconnection Tongs. With
>   the clip or tongs apply pressure to the release collar; this releases
>   the grab ring teeth. At the same time the pressure is being applied,
>   pull on the tube with a twisting action to remove the tube. Ref:
>   http://www.sharkbiteplumbing.com/faq

With other fittings, the one way metal barbs inside may not have a release mechanism and, if that's the case, your only option is to cut the pipe (or elbow).